# How do I access the first item(or xth item) in a PyQuery query?

Tags: python, pyquery

I have a query for a one of my tests that returns 2 results.
Specifically the 3rd level of an outline found using

```
query = html("ul ol ul")
```

How do I select the first or second unordered list?

```
query[0]
```

decays to a HTMLElement

```
list(query.items())[0]
```

or

```
query.items().next() #(in case of the first element)
```

is there any better way that I can't see?

note:

```
query = html("ul ol ul :first")
```

gets the first element of each list not the first list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [PyQuery documentation on traversing](http://pythonhosted.org/pyquery/traversing.html#traversing), you should be able to select the first unordered list by using:

```
query('ul').eq(0)
```

Thus the second unordered list can be obtained by using:

```
query('ul').eq(1)
```

Comment: Why did they pick eq? such a bad name, makes me think of ==/__eq__

Comment: Agreed. Completely counter-intuitive.

Answer (score 2):

In jQuery one would use

```
html("ul ol ul").first()
```

> [.first()](http://api.jquery.com/first/) - Reduce the set of matched elements to the first in the set.

or

```
html("ul ol ul").eq(0)
```

> [.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) - Reduce the set of matched elements to the one at the specified index.

Comment: True, but PyQuery doesn't support the first wayt unfortunately.